# javascript opposite of debugger keyword

Tags: javascript, debugging, javascript-debugger

Javascript has a keyword **debugger** which can be used as a coding style insertion of debug point. This keyword is supposed to be ignored if there is no debugging facility available [[MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger).
But when I used it kind of paused the javascript at the debugger statement. I tried following code on firefox and chrome. Although, this is a desirable functionality for me. I want a trigger like button click to bring back the execution.

JSFiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/VD9y3/

complete code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function print100() {
    for ( var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "<br>" + x;
        debbuger;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="print100()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is a typo in your code. It should be debugger; - you have debbuger; that is why it has stopped at that point.

Comment: Thanks Donal. You are correct. Its my mistake. Is there any way to pause the execution of javascript and resume it like I am trying to without the developer tools ? Or Can this be simulated in some way. I wan't to show the flow of algorithms on my website along side the animated data structure changes.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Is there some statement or keyword which resumes the execution?